# is it safe to dynamically generate form using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

My teachers have always pointed out that client side validation can be easily overcome if the user tries to do so. Therefore functionalities such as validation must be also performed on the server side for a more secure web site.

Since I have started to make a site I need to give the user possibility to clone/duplicate the form for multiple submissions at once. I have done this using jquery.

```
$(wrapper).append( //wrapper contains id of main div
  // some append form code
)
```

Given that my js code generates this form and appends it below, can the user get any information out of it if he/she so desires and, is there a better way of dynamically generating code if javascript is unsafe or not optimal?

Comment: The user (client) can get any information out of *anything* you send to the client, including the source Javascript. Not really anything you can hide on that front.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm also implementing node in my site and i'm ejs module if you know about it. As i'm sending variables using express and ejs, is it possible for the client to access those too?